# Is there any SDK in flutter in which we can see seven live streamers on same screen?

Tags: flutter, live-streaming

I am developing a flutter application, in which I want 7 Live streamers on same page , like in Instagram live stream we can add only two, I used agora.io SDK for Livestreaming, I implemented with single user but find difficulties with multiple uses.

Comment: https://doc-en.zego.im/en/5599.html check this one

Comment: sure let me check

Answer (score 3):

Why you try other one,agora already suported 7 at most live streamer at a time.
https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/capacity
[image]

for more detail regarding agora setup in flutter,
see its main document

https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_flutter?platform=Flutter